# MongoDB&NodeJS : record have no "_id" and "{'

Tags: node.js, mongoose, record

I inserted new records to mongodb, but there are no "_id" and "{".

```
var data = "col1,col2,col3\n1,2,3\n,4,5,6\n7,8,9";
var arr = data.toString().split("\n");
var header = arr[0].split(',');
var tmp = [];
 for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
  var new_file = new TestModel();
  tmp = arr[i].split(',');
  for(var k=0;k<header.length;k++) {
   new_file.set(header[k], tmp[k]);
  }
  new_file.save(function(err,obj){ //save DB
      if(err) return console.error(err);
  });
}
```

Then, If I find new records in mongodb, it returns..

```
" : "1\r", "col2" : "2", "col3" : "3", "__v" : 0 }
" : "4\r", "col2" : "5", "col3" : "6", "__v" : 0 }
" : "7\r", "col2" : "8", "col3" : "9", "__v" : 0 }
```

**Edited:**
Actually my data is CVS file data, file is :

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
....
```

If I print new_file before save into DB,

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(new_file);
```

It returns

```
{"col3\r":"3\r","col2":"2","col1":"1"}
{"col3\r":"6\r","col2":"5","col1":"4"}
...
```

I think CSV file's each lines additionally have "\r" So problem was in split() method.

Then does mongodb have a error when filed name has '\r'?

Comment: what is `header` and what is `set` method doing?

Comment: How are you finding the new records from mongo, Paste some code here please.

Comment: It actually looks like a bad scroll position or something, rather than the lack of the { and _id.

Comment: mongodb code is just db.collection.find().limit(3).

Comment: @ravishankar the set method is new_file.set('filename', 'value') . header is for each field's name. I edited it.

Comment: i am asking what is the use of `set` method, what is it doing?